# 'path misformatted' - local server can't resolve address that uses delimiters -

Tags: .htaccess, url, xampp, delimiter, http-status-code-403

I try to run a website (which works online) on my local server. The site loads without problems, but when I click links with a certain format I get this errors in the X:\xampp\apache\logs:

access.log
`::1 - - [18/Jan/2024:14:56:53 +0100] "GET /xtc2/Agip-Novecento:::16131.html HTTP/1.1" 403 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"`

error.log
`[Thu Jan 18 14:56:53.289002 2024] [core:error] [pid 3600:tid 1880] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:52392] AH00127: Cannot map GET /xtc2/Agip-Novecento:::16131.html HTTP/1.1 to file`

When I rewrite the link according to the rule in the X:\xampp\htdocs\xtc2\.htaccess

```
  ##-- Use colon delimiter ":" for SEO-URLS (default setting)
  ##-- Categories (:::)
  RewriteRule :::([_0-9]+):([_0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?cPath=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule :::([_0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?cPath=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I get a '404 / Forbidden / You don't have permission to access this resource.'

The local server: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/7.4.33 Server at localhost Port 80 on a Win 10 machine.

I edited the htacces and manually edited the links, which I tested on different servers.

Comment: "I get a '404 / Forbidden / " - That's a 403, not a 404.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is you are testing this on a Windows server and `:` (colon) is not a permitted character in Windows filenames. This is a limitation of the Windows OS.

When you make a request to the webserver (Apache in this case), the request gets mapped to the filesystem. It is at this point the "403 Forbidden" response occurs. Unfortunately, `.htaccess` is processed after the request has already been mapped to the filesystem, so this cannot be resolved in `.htaccess`.

You might be able to use these rules instead directly in the server config/`<VirtualHost>` container (not in a `<Directory>` container). This is then processed much earlier - before the request is mapped to the filesystem. However, your rules would need to be modified slightly. For example:

```
RewriteRule :::([_0-9]+):([_0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?cPath=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule :::([_0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?cPath=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note the slash prefix on the *substitution* string.

However, this still might not resolve the issue. Ordinarily, you would "redirect" such requests (in the server config) to *remove* these invalid chars.

> ```
> ##-- Use colon delimiter ":" for SEO-URLS (default setting)
> ```

If you want to run this software on a Windows machine then I would recommend changing the (default) delimiter that is used in URLs.

Comment: >(colon) is not a permitted character in Windows filenames

A link like

    http://localhost/xtc2/164/20-Clutch/Clutch-kits/Clutch-kit-Spider-3-0-V6-164-V6-228mm::26796.html

does work.

But I'll migrate the site to a Linux installation. Sorry for answering this late. Sometimes I'm not here for a while. Thanks so far.